# How can I send info from an arduino to server running on meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, arduino

I am trying to send some very simple data from an arduino with an ethernet shield to my meteor app and enter it into a mongodb collection. With what I came up with so far, I can add info into a collection with this iron-router route in the server when I enter the path into the browser:

```js
this.route('enter', {
    path: '/enter/:_id',
    data: function (){
      _id  = this.params._id;
      return Meteor.call('addMessage', _id);
    }
});
```

I figured if I sent a simple GET request from the arduino with the data put into the path like "http://my-app-name.meteor.com/enter/some-message", that this would work even if there wasn't any GET info in the message but I'm probably wrong about that. Here is my request code for the arduino:

```js
void connectToServer() {
  // attempt to connect, and wait a millisecond:
  Serial.println("connecting to server...");
  if (client.connect(serverName, 80)) { // serverName is "ijsnow.meteor.com"
    Serial.println("making HTTP request...");
    // make HTTP GET request to the server:
    client.println("GET /enter/message-from-arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("HOST: ijsnow.meteor.com");
    client.println();
  }
  // note the time of this connect attempt:
  lastAttemptTime = millis();
}
```

I get the message in the serial monitor that it is making the request but nothing changes in my mongodb collection on that server.

1. Is there something I need to do differently in my meteor app? I know it would be better if I sent it as an actual GET or POST request but I can't figure out how to process the data in meteor.
2. Does anyone know if there is better way that I should be sending the data to my meteor app with?

Sorry if this was confusing or if this is a dumb way to do this but I'd like to use meteor for this app if possible!

Thanks in advance for any answers or feedback!

Answer (score 0):

For connectables, I run a net server inside Meteor that can accept raw TCP packets from just about anything.

For arduino specific stuff, check out johnny-five and this repo for some good stuff: https://github.com/Goyapa/mongoduinometeor

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like johnny-five won't work for me because I want the arduino to be able to have the code running on itself and not a host computer. Wheres a good place to check out recieving TCP packets in my meteor app?

Comment: You want to run meteor on an arduino? O_o

Comment: No I would just have the normal language on the arduino and send information to my server on my meteor app

Comment: ohh, ok, yeah you'll want to use the net package built into node https://nodejs.org/api/net.html